# Passing data between View Controllers with NSNotificationCenter

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

everyone. I wrote this code to pass data between VCs but I'm not sure why it's not working.

Here's the code in ViewController1:-

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

let foodDict: [String:String] = [
    "Orange": "Fruit",
    "Carrot": "Vegetable",
    "Pear": "Fruit",
    "Spinach": "Vegetable"
]

class ViewController1: UIViewController {

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("SEND_STRING", object: nil, userInfo: foodDict)

     }
 }
```

In ViewController2:-

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "printStringDict:", name: "SEND_STRING", object: nil)
    }

    func printStringDict(notification: NSNotification) {

        print("Got the notification...")
        let foodDictFromVC1 = notification.userInfo as! [String:String]
        print(foodDictFromVC1)
    }

}
```

VC2 doesn't get the dictionary (since nothing prints). Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is "Got the notification..." being printed in the console? Sounds to me that VC2 isn't loaded before VC1 thus the observer doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Does an instance of `ViewController2` exist at the time that the `viewDidLoad` function of `ViewController1` is called? Only observers that exist at the time of the notification are told about the notification.

Comment: BTW - this isn't really a good approach. But it's hard to be sure without knowing the relationship between the two view controllers.

Comment: Nothing gets printed to the console. VC1 has a button which segues to VC2 when clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'm relatively new to this. I've used segues and delegates to pass data but I'm trying to learn NSNotification. Any suggestions on a better way to do it?

Comment: You should be passing data through your segue rather than a notification. Notifications are generally used to let multiple objects or objects that don't have a link between them there is a state that has changed. The code you've written to dispatch and observe a notification is correct. Its just the order in which its faulting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So problem is that you post notification but your VC2 is not initialised yet so no-one can get this post that you have in view did load in VC1. It is better to use prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) function to communicate between two ViewControllers connected with segue for e.g.:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation



class ViewController1: UIViewController {

    let foodDict: [String:String] = [
        "Orange": "Fruit",
        "Carrot": "Vegetable",
        "Pear": "Fruit",
        "Spinach": "Vegetable"
    ]
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segueIdentifierSetInStoryboard" {
            if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController2{
                destinationVC.printStringDict(foodDict)
            }
        }
    }
}

class ViewController2: UIViewController {       
    func printStringDict(fooDict:[String:String]) {
        print(fooDict)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use singleton alternatively it will allows you to keep foodDict in one place and any ViewController can have access to it.

Comment: No, don't use a singleton.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Kamil. I'm aware of the segue method but I'm trying to see if there's a way to do the same with notifications. It looks to be impossible.

Comment: @Wertever If you want an answer using notifications, why did you accept this answer? It can easily be done with notifications. You just need to post the notification after the observer is setup to receive it.

Comment: @Wertever Yes you can, but notification are not way to communicate between two object. It is better to use notification when you actually don't know when your action will be triggered. Even when you have communication one to many object it is better in my opinion to use observing designing pattern because notification makes your code less readable and it harder to debug.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand :
ViewController1 -> ViewController2

In that case, your code will never work because, in ViewController1 you post a notification but nothing is listening to your notification because ViewController2 hasn't been created yet !

In ViewController2, you add an observer that listen to any notification that fit a name "SEND_STRING". To make notification works, you have to add an observer on ViewController1 and then trigger a post notification on ViewController2! => ViewController1 will be notified !